# How to get values from ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating tests for my application.

When a quotation_request is created I send out a confirmation email to the user. I also send out an email to inform the proofreaders.

I'm still learning Ruby and I'm sure there is a better way to write the following code:

```
def email_exists?(email_address)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.each do |m|
        if m[:to].to_s == email_address
            return true
        end
    end
end

def email_with_subject_exists?(email_address, email_subject)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.each do |m|
        if m[:to].to_s == email_address && m[:subject].to_s == email_subject
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

I have found that if I don't include return false then for some reason the entire contents of the email get output.

Any help to improve this code would be appreciated.

Here are the contents of ActionMailer::Base.deliveries:

```
[#<Mail::Message:70094817191440, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: peterjohnson1@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdb1b5f4_2ab93fc03545e1f850559@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome to the ProvenWord team!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdb16e49_2ab93fc03545e1f85046d"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>, #<Mail::Message:70094829223120, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: peterjohnson2@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdb23188_2ab93fc03545e1f850725@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome to the ProvenWord team!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdb229aa_2ab93fc03545e1f8506be"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>, #<Mail::Message:70094772574660, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: peterjohnson3@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdb28936_2ab93fc03545e1f850960@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome to the ProvenWord team!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdb27bf6_2ab93fc03545e1f850835"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>, #<Mail::Message:70094829778220, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: peterjohnson4@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdb2c982_2ab93fc03545e1f85116b@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome to the ProvenWord team!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdb2c064_2ab93fc03545e1f85104b"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>, #<Mail::Message:70094829991680, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: peterjohnson5@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdb30c2b_2ab93fc03545e1f85135c@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome to the ProvenWord team!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdb30465_2ab93fc03545e1f85123c"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>, #<Mail::Message:70094777280260, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 15:50:35 +0700>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: johnpeters@example.com>, <Message-ID: <57c7ebdbb8421_2ab93fc03545e1f8515e5@Mitchell-Goulds-MacBook-Air.local.mail>>, <Subject: Your ProvenWord quotation request has been delivered>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_57c7ebdbb76fa_2ab93fc03545e1f8514ee"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>]
```

Comment: You're using #each the wrong way here. If you just want to FIND the email(s), use #filter/#find. #each will return the Enum. i.e. ```[1,2].each { |i| i == 1 }``` returns ```[1,2]```, so your function is returning ```ActionMailer::Base.deliveries```. Your #each is performing work but not doing/returning anything

Comment: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.select {|m| m[:to].to_s == QuotationRequest.last.client.email } still returns the contents of ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

Comment: Do they all match the email address? #select returns all true ```[1,2].select {|i| i>0 }``` returns ```[1,2]```. #find returns the first true ```[1,2].find {|i| i>0 }``` returns ```1```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I achieved with the help of Peter R.

```
class EmailHelper

        #checks if the email exists in ActionMailer::Base to see if it was sent and to the correct email address
        def email_exists?(email_address)
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.select {|m| m.to.include?(email_address)}
        end

        def email_with_subject_exists?(email_address, email_subject)
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.select {|m| (m.to.include?(email_address) && m.subject.include?(email_subject))}
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually do it like this (this is with RSpec)

```
it "sends correct email" do
  UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.tap do |mail|
    expect(mail.from).to eq(["myapp@awesome.com"])
    expect(mail.subject).to eq("Welcome #{user.name}")
  end
end
```

EDIT:

There are a couple of ways to do it. I personally like to keep the logic seperated between what gets sent, and what the message contains.

Controller(preferably)/Model(maybe) action is like this:

```
def something
  Mailer.a(item).deliver
  Mailer.b(item).deliver
end
```

Test the right emails get send:

```
it "sends correct number of emails" do
  expect do
    ## Trigger your stuff here (#something above)
  end.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }.by(2)
end
```

EDIT2: ^^this^^ won't actually test that the *correct* two emails get sent. For that you can do something like `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.map{|e| e[:subject]}.sort == ["asubject", "bsubject"].sort` but then this is britte when you change the subjects. Up to you what you want to do/test here. (also look as `assert Mailer.recieves(:a).with(obj)` (I forget the exact syntax and I dont know what testing framework you are using, but they all have something similar to that.)

Test the email content is correct

```
it "Mailer#a has correct email content" do
  Mailer.a(user).deliver
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.tap do |mail|
    expect(mail.from).to eq(["myapp@awesome.com"])
    expect(mail.subject).to eq("Welcome #{user.name}")
  end
end
## repeat for Mailer#b
```

Comment: In my application I want to test that the correct emails are sent after a new quotation_request is created.  Many are sent so for these tests I can't use last.  I have to actually search for them using a specific email.  Do you have an example of how to do this using filter/find?

Comment: I agree that checking the subject would be very brittle. I will change that to check for a link to the quotation request as that must be present.  I like how you divided up the tests into a and b segments.  On my features test for sending in the form for a quotation request I want to test that the correct emails are sent out upon submission of the form. I will test the mailers too. I use Rspec.  Thank you Peter for taking the time to assist me with this. So much to learn.

Comment: puts ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.select {|m| m.to.include?(email_address)}  returns the ActionMailer::Base mail object. Any ideas